Unable to load flag dialog popup on some deleted questions
In the last ten days, I've been unable to load the flag dialog on two recently deleted questions:

Question #402226 today and
Question #402001 ten days ago

Instead of displaying the flag popup when I click the [Flag] button, a toast message saying:

Unable to load popup - please try again

is displayed.
In the page, the request for the flag popup HTML appears to be correctly made, but receives a response that is the "Oops! Something Bad Happened - Meta Stack Exchange" page. The page JavaScript correctly recognizes that something went wrong and displays the toast message.
I encountered this issue, not because I actually wanted to flag the questions, but because a userscript I have that shows a preview of the post first requests the flag dialog. I, thus, request the post's flag dialog quite a bit more often than usual. In order to make sure it's not a userscript issue, I've duplicated the issue in a stock browser profile without any userscripts.
The problem persists for me on both questions in a fresh Firefox ver. 128.0.3 profile with no userscripts or extensions and on Chrome ver. 127.0.6533.120 (Official Build) (64-bit), both on Windows 10, and Chrome on iOS using cellular data (i.e., not using the same ISP). The problem does not occur on any other posts which I've tried (lots on many sites, but primarily SO, MSO, and MSE). The problem on the question from 2024-08-08 has been consistent every time I've tried it since it was deleted ten days ago. The problem did not occur on either question prior to the question being deleted.

Unable to reproduce. The flag dialog loads just fine for me on the two questions you link.

@SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Interesting. The problem persists for me on both questions for me in a fresh Firefox ver. 128.0.3 profile with no userscripts or extensions and on Chrome ver. 127.0.6533.120 (Official Build) (64-bit). The problem does not occur on any other posts which I've tried. The problem on the question from 2024-08-08 has been consistent every time I've tried it since it was deleted ten days ago. The problem did not occur on either question prior to the question being deleted.

works for me too (win10+ Version 127.0.6533.120 (Official Build) (64-bit)) https://i.sstatic.net/EaJJe5ZP.png

FWIW, trying to load the flag dialog also works fine for me for both of those questions on Windows 10, using the Microsoft Edge browser (Version 127.0.2651.105 (Official build) (64-bit)).
